# Get file identifier from fileObject in TYPO3 API

Tags: typo3

i am learning how to deal with files and file-refences in TYPO3. This line get me the correct file objects:

```
$fileObject = $fileRepository->findByRelation('fe_users', 'image', $uidOfUser);
```

But how do i get the file identifier from this object? (In fluid it would be no problem, but i can't use fluid here).

Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `FileRepository::findByRelation()` [returns a list of file reference objects](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html#getting-referenced-files), not a single file reference:

```php
$fileReferences = $fileRepository->findByRelation('fe_users', 'image', $uidOfUser);
```

Then you can iterate the file references or pick the first to retrieve the identifier:

```php
if (!empty($fileReferences[0])) {
    $fileIdentifier = $fileReferences[0]->getIdentifier();
}
```

Notice that you can also get no file references at all, thus an empty list. So make sure the reference you try to access actually exists.

Comment: OK, i understand now ... the available methods are found in TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\AbstractFile - getName(), getSize() etc. Very nice - thank you!